# how to manage multiple files, global variables, and defines

Tags: c++, class, header, include

I have two classes, class "entity and class "tile".

Class "entity" has some member functions that uses a global array of type "tile". It also uses some defined numbers.

Class "tile" contains a member variable that's a pointer to type "entity".

I want to separate the classes into various .h files. I'm going to try and restructure it, but I do want to know if it's possible to do this.

So, again, for clarity:

"entity" uses global 2d array of type "tile"

"tile" uses

Is there any way to split this up into three .h files (one for each class, and one for all the global variables and defines)?

Thanks!

Comment: redesign such that you don't need the globals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see it why do you need three *.h* files. Just make a unit for each class, and put the global into *Entity*'s module (I wouldn't argue that you could possibly avoid globals).

*Entity.h*

```
class Entity
{
<...>
};
```

*Entity.cpp*

```
#include "Entity.h"
#include "Tile.h"

Tile array[100];//here's your array
```

*Tile.h*

```
#include "Entity.h"

class Tile
{
    <...>
    Entity * ptr;//here's your pointer
};
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked, but I don't seem to be able to access the array in the main function. How could I do that?

This is a good alternate way to do it, but for the sake of having all global variables in one location, is it possible to have a separate file (like global.h) instead of putting the global in the entity's module?

Comment: @Nathan, you shouldn't do that (put the array to the .h, that is). To access the array from another module (i.e. your main), you should use `extern` keyword: `extern Tile array[100]`.

Comment: Thanks! It compiles cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need a forward declare on class Entity?

tile.h:

```
class Entity;

class Tile {
     Entity *entity;
      ...
}
```

entity.h:

```
//#include "tile.h" - add this back if you need to refer to tile in Entity defn

class Entity {
    ...
}
```

entity.cpp

```
#include "entity.h"
// Remove the following or put in proper include protection if you uncomment the 
// include above
#include "tile.h"

Tile gbl[10][10];
```